# Google Map API Returning Blank Response

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Here are the code i am using to get google Map, But i am a getting blank map on response.

```
function initialize(address) {
    jQuery('#mapgoogle').show();
    jQuery('#store_img_default').hide();
    var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng( 50,50 ),
    myOptions = {
        zoom: 12,
        center: myLatLng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    },
    map = new google.maps.Map( document.getElementById( 'mapgoogle'  ), myOptions ),
    marker = new google.maps.Marker( {position: myLatLng, map: map} );
    marker.setMap( map );
    moveMarker( map, marker,address );   
}
```

Below is the Response from googleMap.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/pcf22.png

This code was fully working since last 6 months, and suddenly this creating issues. Any help in this will be highly appreciable.

Comment: What is the value of `address`?  How are you calling `initialize`?

Comment: Better yet, please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that exhibits the issue.

Comment: which API-version do you load? Pleasde post the function `moveMarker`

Comment: <script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false" type="text/javascript"></script>

Comment: I am passing comma separated latitude and longitude value to address. exp: address="23.75656,45.4545"                                                          and also using version v3 of google API's and following is the script to load map plugin

Comment: function moveMarker(map, marker, address) {

    //delayed so you can see it move
    setTimeout(function() {

        marker.setPosition(new google.maps.LatLng(address.split(',')[0], address.split(',')[1]));
        map.panTo(new google.maps.LatLng(address.split(',')[0], address.split(',')[1]));

    }, 1500);                                                                                                                           I am calling initialilize on load of page through javascript.